# if body has class Fade in mp3 sound else fade out

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, html5-audio

I am trying to fade the volume of an mp3 in to 1 if the body has the class fp-viewing-0
How ever this isn't working and the volume doesn't change how can I fix this?

Code:

```
var audio0 = document.getElementById('audio-0');
audio0.volume = 0;

setInterval( function(){
          if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-0")) {
             audio0.animate({volume: 1}, 1000);
            }

else {
   audio0.animate({volume: 0}, 1000);
            }

 }, 100);
```

HTML

```
<audio id="audio-0"  src="1.mp3" autoplay="autoplay"></audio>
```

I've also tried:

```
$("#audio-0").prop("volume", 0);


setInterval( function(){
          if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-0")) {
            $("#audio-0").animate({volume: 1}, 3000);
            }

else {
   $("#audio-0").animate({volume: 0}, 3000);
            }

 }, 100);
```

Kind Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the jquery animate part to a fade made by hand. For that i created a fade time and steps count to manipulate the fade effect.

```
var audio0 = document.getElementById('audio-0');
audio0.volume = 0;

if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-0")) {
     audio0.volume = 1; //max volume
     var fadeTime = 1500; //in milliseconds 
     var steps = 150; //increasing makes the fade smoother
     var stepTime = fadeTime/steps;
     var audioDecrement = audio0.volume/steps;

     var timer = setInterval(function(){
         audio0.volume -= audioDecrement; //fading out

         if (audio0.volume <= 0.03){ //if its already inaudible stop it
              audio0.volume = 0;
              clearInterval(timer); //clearing the timer so that it doesn't keep getting called
         }
     }, stepTime);
}
```

Better would be to place all of this in a function that receives these values a fades accordingly so that it gets organized:

```
function fadeAudio(audio, fadeTime, steps){ 
    audio.volume = 1; //max 
    steps = steps || 150; //turning steps into an optional parameter that defaults to 150
    var stepTime = fadeTime/steps;
    var audioDecrement = audio.volume/steps;

    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        audio.volume -= audioDecrement;

        if (audio.volume <= 0.03){ //if its already inaudible stop it
             audio.volume = 0;
             clearInterval(timer);
        }
    }, stepTime);
}
```

Which would make your code a lot more compact and readable:

```
var audio0 = document.getElementById('audio-0');
audio0.volume = 0;
if ($("body").hasClass("fp-viewing-0")) {
    fadeAudio(audio0, 1500);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! how would I go about the else statement if the if condition fades the audio in what can i put in the else condition to make the audio fade out?

Comment: @Neths I'm not sure i understood your question. This `if` in the last block fades the audio if you have the  `fp-viewing-0` class in the `body` otherwise it doesn't do anything. Also it has the `volume = 0` previously. So the final result is, it fades the audio if the class exists, otherwise you wont hear anything. If you remove the `audio0.volume=0` above then it fades if the class exists, otherwise it keeps the audio playing.